# starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name "static" and params "filename". in FastAPI Error

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi, starlette

As you know this error is output by class Router in routing.py
I am developing a service with FastAPI as just REST API not using HTML files
But I should to append HTML output script in my source code because an external service need to redirect to my api service page

So I appended Jinja2Templates and succeed to call HTML template
After that I appended bootstrap template to static folder and mount this folder
But I can not mount for a router which is separated each endpoint file

Someone support me if you know the issue

## Directory tree

```
another projects
target project
|- src
   |- app
      |- main.py
      |- controllers
         |- page_controller.py
      |- endpoints
         |- from_external_redirec.py
      |- routes
         |- api.py
      |- schemas
      |- static    <- added this needs
      |- templates <-- added this needs
         |- success.html
         |- fault.html
```

Note. this directory is for some docker containers. Target project is one of containers

## main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from .app.routes.api import router as api_router

app = FastAPI(
    title="xxxxxxxx",
    description="xxxxx",
    version="0.0.1",
)

absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path = "app/static"
static_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)

app.include_router(api_router)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=static_path), name="static")
```

Note. StaticeFiles uses target project as default directory.So if set 'app/static' to directory parameter then FastAPI show 'app/static' not found
So I set relative path instead

### FYI. Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /code
RUN mkdir -p /code/src
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload", "--env-file", "/code/src/env/docker/.env"]
```

### FYI Docker compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  target-project:
    build:
      context: ./target-project/
    volumes:
      - ./target-project/src/:/code/src/

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - target-project
```

Note. This docker container uses resources under src directory

## api.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from ..endpoints import from_external_redirec

router = APIRouter()
router.include_router(from_external_redirec.router)
```

## from_external_redirec.py

```
from fastapi import status as st, APIRouter, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse
from fastapi.requests import Request
from requests import request
import os
from ..controllers.page_controller import pagectl

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/external",
    tags=["External"],
)

@router.get("/result/success/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def show_success_page(request: Request):
    page = pagectl()
        return page.get_successful_template(request)
    return page.get_error_template(request)
    
@router.get("/result/cancel/{payment_id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def show_falt_page(request: Request):
    page = pagectl()
    return page.get_cancel_template(request)
```

## page_controller.py

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.requests import Request
import os

class pagectl:
    def __init__(self):
        absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        relative_path = "../templates"
        template_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)
        self.template = Jinja2Templates(directory=template_path)
    
    def show_success_page(self, request: Request):
        return self.__get_template(request, "success.html")
        
    def show_fault_page(self, request: Request):
        return self.__get_template(request, "fault.html")

    def __get_template(self, request: Request, file: str):
        return self.template.TemplateResponse(
            file,
            {
                "request": request,
            }
        )
```

Comment: This is probably cause by your template, which you haven't included - it seems like you're using the `url_for` syntax from Flask and not the one from FastAPI/Starlette. It should be `url_for('static', path='/foo/bar.css')` - `path` - not `filename`.

Comment: I see, your answer is so smart... it's easy to add get function for static path
Actually, I found for_url doesn't return direct path so I added _enternal option but it is error in FastAPI case...
Thanks I'll try one

Comment: I changed filename to path in url_for parameter but the result is not direct path
for example, If my fastapi endpoint http://mydot.com so url_for output to use this domain path but actually url_for outputs xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for my server address
and _external option is not working in FastAPI

Comment: I mean
<link href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/static/css/my.css" rel="stylesheet">
not
<link href="http://mydot.com/static/css/my.css" rel="stylesheet">